# Is there an easy way to only show the play and stop button from the html5 audio player?

Tags: php, html, audio

I have been searching all night and all I find is a lot of java script stuff.
Is there a way to hide everything from the html5 audio player and only have a play and stop button?

Comment: Ofcourse there is, a broad answer on a broad question. Perhaps you should take a look on [ask] a question. We help with code, not write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this help?

```
<audio id="playaudio" src="hello.ogg"></audio>
<div>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('playaudio').play()">Play</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('playaudio').pause()">Pause</button>
</div>
```